# VS Code Terminal Printing Several Folder Paths before rnning Python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently started using `VS Code` for `Python`.

I realized that when I hit debug/F5, `VS Code` prints several folder paths (locations of workspace, Python.exe, host, Port, etc.) in Terminal window before debugging the code.

I am using `Windows 7` machine.

Why is that and how can I avoid it?
Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

It's by design and required in order to run the debugger, so there's no way to avoid it.